# How to add space between two lines of a string in C#?

Tags: c#, string

How can I add space between two lines of a string?

For Example:

```
string words = "Twelve Million Three Hundred and Forty-Five\n Thousand Six Hundred Seventy-Eight Only"
```

**Appears As:**

[image]

**Desired Result:**

[image]

Thanks.

Re-Edited: Sorry Theres already backslash N there, I don't want a new line, I already have a new line, it's just I need space between two lines, I think it's Called Leading Spaces.

**Check This: The Second String is way above the line.**
[image]

Comment: Where are you displaying this text? In the console? Or are you writing it to a file?

Comment: I'm printing this on a "Printed Form" that has two lines.

I cannot able to put the second string on the second line, its going over the second line.

Comment: Can you show the details of how you are doing that?

Comment: @Fawad have you tried using `\n` twice?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Please re-check my post in 2 minutes, I'm uploading image.

Comment: Can you show the code how you are doing this? Your code example should be complete. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Use [Environment.NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
string words = "Twelve Million Three Hundred and Forty-Five" + Environment.NewLine + "Thousand Six Hundred Seventy-Eight Only";
```

If you want to add an empty line between the two lines, use Environment.NewLine twice like this:

```
string words = "Twelve Million Three Hundred and Forty-Five" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Thousand Six Hundred Seventy-Eight Only";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use string format instead of '+' to prevent reallocation of memory.

Todo:

```
string words = string.format("{0}{1}{2}","Twelve Million Three Hundred and Forty-Five",Environment.NewLine,"Thousand Six Hundred Seventy-Eight Only");
```

Not Todo:

```
string words = "Twelve Million Three Hundred and Forty-Five" + Environment.NewLine + "Thousand Six Hundred Seventy-Eight Only";
```

Comment: as far as i knew, and please correct me if I'm wrong, strings are allocated with a certain amount memory and by adding to it using '+' with a long string might cause reallocation, to find enough memory to the new string. That's why there's string builder and string format (more than just formating)

Comment: In any case, all this is secondary; the important thing is that it has not relevance on actual performance. `String.format` might be better because of different reasons, a noticeable improvement in performance/memory-management is not one of them.

Comment: I agree but if you are handling strings that you are not familiar with their length, you better use format, just in case they are too long for the initial memory allocation.

Comment: Actually, I will better include for-sure-right ideas. The only relevant idea here is that there is no problem from a performance perspective (unless under extreme conditions and, even in that cases, it should be checked) in using `+` or `string.format` (or similar concatenation alternative). The string type has certain peculiarities which makes the corresponding allocation of memory a bit tricky; but as far as this is irrelevant from the "macroscopic" point of view and there is no other alternative, it doesn't need to be brought into picture.

Comment: In summary: to be able to feel any kind of difference between a string formed with `string.format` (or similar) and one formed from mere assignations (+), you would have to concatenate millions of substrings (and even in that case, I wouldn't be too sure regarding the fastest alternative). You might save much more memory just by relying on the adequate numeric types (or by avoiding high-memory consuming collections, etc.). In a list of 1 million things to change in order to improve the performance, this fact wouldn't even be included. This is the only important point here :)